# Redis cluster live reshard failure

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

We're using redis-cluster extensively in our production env. We currently have a 30 node cluster (15 masters, 15 slaves) 
We're trying to increase the cluster, for that we've created new servers & joined them to the cluster. so far all is well.

Next - we're trying to reshard the slots to the new masters. we wrote a script that does this, using the `redis-trib` `reshard` command.

However - the migration fails midway (but not very far from the start) with this error: 

`[ERR] Calling MIGRATE: ERR Target instance replied with error: BUSYKEY Target key name already exists.`

This happens sporadically, at times it manages to move some slots before failing, at times it fails on the first slot.
Each such failure requires a manual fixing operation which makes the reshard operation very hard to manage.

We have not found any concrete example of this, nor any idea on how to prevent this other than a downtime migration. which we are trying to avoid.

Versions:
redis server 4.0.2
redis trib 3.3.3 (downgraded from 4.0.2 following this issue : [redis cluster reshard [ERR] Calling MIGRATE: ERR Syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774093/redis-cluster-reshard-err-calling-migrate-err-syntax-error))

Our next step is to upgrade to latest redis (4.0.11), even though we didn't find any indication in the release notes of this issue.

Hoping to hear we're doing something wrong and how to fix it, or is redis-cluster not built for live resharding ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have faced like this problem while working with redis-clustering support for our own project. I found a problem with the `redis-trib reshard` command. It works fine if no key is stored in slots those are migrating from one master to another.

> But redis-5 (still developing, not stable yet) has it's own
>   `redis-cli' that has no problem with resharding command I think. Only for lower versions of 5 it happens.

If you look at the official docs for redis say [redis reconfiguration](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#cluster-live-reconfiguration) and [redis cluster resharding](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-setslot#redis-cluster-live-resharding-explained), you'll find what they do internally to reshard.

So I solved the problem by doing those tasks by running a bash script instead of running `redis-trib reshard` command.

Suppose you want to reshard some slots from a master node to other master node. We'll call the node that has the current ownership of the hash slot the **source node**, and the node where we want to migrate the **destination node**.

For each slot do the following steps:

> Remember that the order of these steps is important here according to redis official docs.

1. Send `CLUSTER SETSLOT <slot> IMPORTING <source-node-id>` to **destination node** to set the **slot** to **importing** state.
2. Send `CLUSTER SETSLOT <slot> MIGRATING <destination-node-id>` to **source node** to set the **slot** to **migrating** state.
3. Get keys from the **source node** with [CLUSTER GETKEYSINSLOT](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-getkeysinslot) command and move them into the **destination node** using the following [MIGRATE](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) command.

   `MIGRATE target_host target_port key target_database_id timeout`

   In Redis Cluster there is no need to specify a database other than 0, but [MIGRATE](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) is a general command that can be used for other tasks not involving Redis Cluster.
4. When the migration process is finally finished, use `CLUSTER SETSLOT <slot> NODE <destination-node-id>` in both **source node** and **destination node** in order to set the slot to their normal state again. The same command is usually sent to all other nodes to avoid waiting for the natural propagation of the new configuration across the cluster.

A simple example bash script to do this is also given here:

source-ip: `172.17.0.5`. source-id: `1f70a5107e0042a7d33a9efaf88dbdfecd78076a`

destination-ip: `172.17.0.4`. destination-id: `7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02`

another master ip: `172.17.0.7`

```
for i in `seq 0 5460`; do
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.4 cluster setslot ${i} importing 1f70a5107e0042a7d33a9efaf88dbdfecd78076a
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.5 cluster setslot ${i} migrating 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
    while true; do
        key=`redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.5 cluster getkeysinslot ${i} 1`
        if [ "" = "$key" ]; then
            echo "there are no key in this slot ${i}"
            break
        fi
        redis-cli -h 172.17.0.5 migrate 172.17.0.4 6379 ${key} 0 5000
    done
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.5 cluster setslot ${i} node 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.4 cluster setslot ${i} node 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
    redis-cli -c -h 172.17.0.7 cluster setslot ${i} node 7e428bae84697a3882ecad19bd0d13ac7ee97d02
done
```

Comment: This also happens in case of redis 5 via redis-cli command for migrating some slots to new master and source node fails in process

Comment: I actually can not say confidently that this will not happen in case redis 5, but I faced and solved this way for redis 4 during redis 4 support for project github.com/kubedb.

Comment: Ok just added to help others

Comment: Answer with full details to figure out what and where the issue is coming. Thanks